# What is the difference between normalized, scaled and integer VkFormats?

Tags: vulkan

Let's take the following 6 `VkFormats` for example:

```
VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM
VK_FORMAT_R8_SNORM
VK_FORMAT_R8_USCALED
VK_FORMAT_R8_SSCALED
VK_FORMAT_R8_UINT
VK_FORMAT_R8_SINT
```

All of these specify a one-component 8-bit format that has a single 8-bit R component.

The formats differ in whether they are (a) *normalized*, (b) *scaled*; or (c) *integer*.  What does that mean?  What are the differences between those three things?  Where is that specified?

Are all 256 possible values of 8-bits meaningful and valid in all six formats?

(They also differ in whether they are *signed* or *unsigned*.  I assume this means whether their underlying types are like the C types `int8_t` or `uint8_t` ?)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Refer to [Identification of Formats](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#_identification_of_formats) and [Conversion from Normalized Fixed-Point to Floating-Point](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#fundamentals-fixedfpconv) in the specification.

- `UNORM` is a `float` in the range of `[0, 1]`.
- `SNORM` is the same but in the range of `[-1, 1]`
- `USCALED` is the unsigned integer value converted to `float`
- `SSCALED` is the integer value converted to `float`
- `UINT` is an unsigned integer
- `SINT` is a signed integer

I.e. for the `VK_FORMAT_R8_*`:

- for `UNORM` raw `0` would give `0.0f`, raw `255` would give `1.0f`
- for `SNORM` raw `-127` (resp. `129`) would give `-1.0f`, raw `127` would give `1.0f`
- `USCALED` raw `0` would give `0.0f`, raw `255` would give `255.0f`
- `SSCALED`raw `-128` (resp. `128`) would give `-128.0f`, raw `127` would give `127.0f`

`-128` (-2<sup>n-1</sup>) is not meaningful in `SNORM`, and simply clamps to `-1.0f`.

Comment: Thanks @krOoze, 32.1.3 was sneakily hiding between the lengthy 31.1 and 31.2 :)

Comment: @krOoze what does the "_unsigned integer value converted to `float`_" imply? Is it that the image buffer contains unsigned integers which are then returned as floats when sampled? Or is it that upon buffering the image, a pointer to unsigned int must be given, whose data is converted to a float storage format?
Am I even asking the right question?

Comment: @alexpanter It means in virtually the same as C++ cast. E.g. if the data (with this format) is represented with 42u raw value, then it yields 42.0f value.

Comment: @krOoze so it's a sampling thing? And in this particular case - the source image data in main memory should be `uint8_t*`. ? And when I sample in a GLSL shader, if as you say the sampled texel contains 42u in memory, the sampler returns 42.0f. ?
And thank you!

Comment: @alexpanter It doesn't have apriori anything to do with sampling (the value can simply be fetched or loaded some other way). Or be written into for that matter. Yea, `USCALED` is (interpreted as) a float type, and its representation is N bits (where N is in the name of the format). The bits are interpreted akin to if you read the bits as `uintN_t` and then (arithmetically) assigned the value to f32. 0b1 yields 1.0f, 0b10 yields 2.0f, 0b11 yields 3.0f, and so on.